# Refrescar mapa IOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, map

Buenas.

Estoy realizando una aplicación que muestra un mapa, y recibe desde un webservice un array con JSOn opbjects, que contienen datos de coordenadas, para luego añadir PINs al mapa, mostrando la ubicación de los usuarios.

La conexión funciona correctamente y los datos se reciben sin problemas, pero el mapa no se refresca, no muestra los PINS, hasta que el usuario de la App hace algo con el mapa (hacer zoom, desplazar el mapa...).

¿Hay alguna forma de forzar el refresco del mapa, una vez que se reciban todos los datos?

Adjunto el código del método de actualizar los datos (el cual es llamado al presionar un botón de la interfaz).

@IBAction func ACTUALIZAR(_ sender: Any) {

```
     let url = URL(string: "http://mi_url.es")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil{

            print("ERROR")

        }else{

            if let content = data{

            do{

                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject


                if let taxis = myJson["taxis"] as? NSArray {                 
                    if let hashTags = myJson["taxis"] as? [[String:String]] {
       self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)

                        for tag in hashTags {

                            let laLongitud:String = tag["longitud"]!
                            let laLatitud:String = tag["latitud"]!

                            self.pintaTaxistas(latitud: laLatitud, longitud: laLongitud)
                         }
                    }

            }else {
                    print("No puedo pintar el array")
                }

                }catch{

                }
            }
        }
    }
     task.resume()

}
```

func pintaTaxistas (latitud:String, longitud:String) {

```
   let lat = Double(latitud) ?? 0.0
   let long = Double(longitud) ?? 0.0
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "Taxi"
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)        
}
```

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, la closure en `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in`

te deja en una `background queue`... Por lo que para poder pintar en la UI necesitarás volver al `mainQueue`.

Prueba esto:

```
func pintaTaxistas (latitud:String, longitud:String) {

   let lat = Double(latitud) ?? 0.0
   let long = Double(longitud) ?? 0.0
   let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
   annotation.title = "Taxi"
   annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
   }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me ha solucionado el problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Nada! Acuérdate de marcar la respuesta como válida si te ayudó

Comment: Marcada está, pero no tengo reputación suficiente para que se vea. En cualquier caso, gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Mmm! Ok... pues nada, no te preocupes! :)

Comment: Pues si que podía aceptar al final, solo que no le había dado donde debía (le había dado donde "respuesta útil", en lugar de a "aceptar"). Lo siento, me acabo de hacer la cuenta y todavía le estoy pillando el punto. ;)